# Allowing https for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm about to lose my mind trying to set this up. I have lost the whole day and can't seem to get near what I want to do.

I have a node js rest api uploaded trough elastic beanstalk, and I'm trying to setup a webpage to present the api, but for the live example to work the api needs to be accessed trough https. I've read the [instructions for setting up the https for elastic beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) (and like everything on the AWS documentation it is a ridiculous maze). It has sent me trough several different AWS services.

What I basically got from it so far is that I need to set up a Load Balancer that will receive the connection trough https and forward the user to my instance. But I can't get it to work. I have a domain from freenom: bibliaparahumanos.tk, it is setup with an A alias to my EC2 IP, and it works with http, but if I try to access it trough https, I get "connection refused". If I use my normal Elastic Beanstalk url (http://apibibliahumana-env.eba-3nbmrphf.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/) with https it works, but I get a warning that the connection is not secure due to the domain on the certificate being different from the domain I'm accessing (which I understand, since the domain in the certificate is for my freenom domain).

I have the Load Balancer Listener set up with:

- Protocol: https
- Port: 443
- Default action: forward to target group

(I have tried the target group with both http and https and the problem remains).

My certificate is from AWS Certificate Manager.

I have also seem this other [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/) but it confused me more. It adds some steps for configuring stuff on the app bundle, but I don't understand if it's required or an alternate way. I have tried setting that up, but it asks me to add the certificate's public key, which I can't figure out how to find.

Comment: Did you verify the ssl properly?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. I have later managed to obtain the public key for the certificate, but following the second tutorial I mentioned, I still don't see the desired solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a CNAME record to your DNS towards apibibliahumana-env.eba-3nbmrphf.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com.

A big advantage of using elastic beanstalk is that you can do blue/green deployments; as you will instead add the app URL to your DNS you can build an entire new environment in elastic beanstalk, test/wait until its stable and swap the app urls; which results in deployments without any downtime.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

Comment: Hi, Max. Hey, this actually kinda works... I had done that with a "www" on my DNS, but hadn't tested it. Though I would really like to figure out why the "A" record doesn't work, since I'd like to have people be able to reach my url without "www", but for my current purpose this is pretty much enough.

Comment: I am not sure why you have this issue. I could help you with pointing your root domain to elastic beanstalk. In Route53 you have the option to add an A record with an alias to elastic beanstalk. Not sure if you currently have your dns in AWS but hope this helps.